# Placing divs side by side... Nothing I have read has worked

Tags: html, css

I have read other posts on stack overflow but none of them have worked so far. The issue I am having is that 2 divs will not sit side by side.

I have a main content div and I have a small appbar div I am trying to put directly to the right of the content.

Everything I have tried has caused the appbar div to go under my footer, or caused the content to go under the container.

```
#appbar {
width:300px;
background-color:orange;
position:relative;
}

#content {
color:black;
width:500px;
}

footer {
height:10%;
opacity:0.8;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Please share your HTML structure, or even better, add a JSFiddle.

Comment: Have you tried float : left ???? OR try <span> instead of <div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id put both the appbar and the content inside a container/wrapper div set to 800px width. Then float both the content and the appbar to left Float:left; then on the footer use clear:both. Bear in mind that the elements will sit side by side , if you want a bit of spacing between them use paddings or margins.

Answer (score 0):

Try floating your elements like this:

```
#appbar{
float:right
}

#content {
float:left
}

#footer {
position:absolute;
clear:both;
```

Comment: That made the div almost non existent to the right of the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Use **display: inline-flex;** in content and appbar.

```
    #appbar {
width:300px;
background-color:orange;
position:relative;
display: inline-flex;
}

#content {
color:black;
width:500px;
display: inline-flex;
}

footer {
height:10%;
opacity:0.8;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: **display: inline** will also work if you don't want to use **inline-flex**